# Remove an array using its key from a nested associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "barw"    => "21",
    "bara"    => "22",
    "barq"    => "25",
    "multix" => array(
         "1" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         ),
        "2" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         ),
    "893" => "bar",
    "563" => "bar",
    "hd8" => "bar",
    "multiv" => array(
         "1" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         ),
         "2" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         ),
    "tw" => "bar",
    "qa" => "bar",
    "op" => "bar"
    )
    )
);
```

which I am reading from and writing to like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

echo "<br/>";
echo $array['multix']['1']['ar1'].'<br/>';
echo "<br/>";
echo $array['multix']['1']['ar2'].'<br/>';
echo "<br/>";
echo $array['multix']['1']['ar3'].'<br/>';
echo "<br/>";
echo $array['multix']['1']['ar4'].'<br/>';
$array['multix']['1']['ar4'] = "lego";
```

However, I am unable to delete an array of my choice like:

```
unset($array['multiv']['1']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

What should I do to delete the array using its key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `multiv` array is inside the `multix` array so you need to prepend the `multix` name

```
unset($array['multix']['multiv']['1']);
```

you may be setting your array wrong if `multiv` was supposed to be one up in the index level.

Comment: To expand on this: after `['multix']['2']` ends, you've reduced the indent on `['893']` but the brackets for `['multix']` are still open. Then, at the bottom, you close two sets of brackets at the same level of indent; the second is for `['multix']`. Move one of those closing brackets up before `['893']` and you should be good.